# GreenDao возможно ли добавить библиотеку в свой модуль. Без создания отдельного модуля.

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Здравствуйте, решил использовать библиотеку [GreenDao](https://github.com/SureCase/GreenDaoForAndroidStudio). В туториале написано, что нужно скачать их пример с гитхаба, и добавить его как отдельный модуль, в проект.

Возможно ли использовать эту библиотеку но не добавлять целый модуль отдельно для работы с ней?
Т.е. в приложении есть 2 модуля: **app** и **core**. По идее, в app будет весь интерфейс, а в core взаимодействие с сервером/бд и тд. Не хочется нарушать эту структуру добавлением третьего модуля.

Comment: Дочитайте описание по ссылке, что вы привели, до конца. В конце, в 6 пункте решение вашей проблемы.

Comment: @metalurgus спасибо вам! Английский меня подвёл. Слово "aware" не смог перевести)